# How to justify text in a flutter column widget?

Tags: flutter

I would like to align left elements vertically and same with right one with padding, here is what I got as a result, the elements are not aligned  and I cannot insert padding in the second row so that left elements are aligned

[image]

```
         return InkWell(
           child: Column(

            children: <Widget>[
               Row(
                 children:<Widget> [
                 Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)),

                 Text(
                 product.libelle,
                 style: theme.textTheme.title,
                 maxLines: 1,
                 textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                 ),]),


             Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children:<Widget> [
              Text(
              product.description,
              style: theme.textTheme.subtitle,
              maxLines: 1,

             ),
         RaisedButton( onPressed: () {},
         child: new Text("S\'abonner"),
         )

       ]),
       ),
         );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you try to wrap second row with Padding widget?

```
Padding(
    padding: EdgetInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0),
    child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children:<Widget> [
              Text(
              product.description,
              style: theme.textTheme.subtitle,
              maxLines: 1,

             ),
         RaisedButton( onPressed: () {},
         child: new Text("S\'abonner"),
         )

       ]),
)
```

Answer (score 22):

Use Text Widget and TextAlign.justify :)

```
Text('my String', textAlign: TextAlign.justify),
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Text( 'Vinay',
**textAlign: TextAlign.justify,**
style:TextStyle() ),
```

*incase of Rich Text*

```
    RichText(  
             **textAlign: TextAlign.justify,**
              text: TextSpan( style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 36),
              children: <TextSpan>[
              TextSpan(text: 'Woolha ', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
              TextSpan(text: 'dot '),
              TextSpan(text: 'com', style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline))]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this 
Just add below 2 line of code inside you Column Widget.

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
```

Answer (score 1):

Your top level widget should be a `Row`, since you want to horizontally position your widgets next to each others. So what you should do instead is use the following structure (pseudocode):

```
Row
  Column
    Text (title)
    Text (subtitle)
  Button
```

It's also important to use the correct alignment properties (`MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` on `Row` so that there is a space between the two main elements and `CrossAxisAlignment.start` + `MainAxisAlignment.center` on `Column` to center things).

I created a pen to demonstrate it: https://codepen.io/rbluethl/pen/QWyNQjE

Hope that helps!